# TornadoFx: Which performs better FXML or type-CSS

Tags: kotlin, javafx-2, tornadofx

I wanted to know if there is any performance benefit of using one over the other with TornadoFx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type safe CSS can be used with both FXML and type safe builders. You need to compare FXML with the type safe builders. The builders are both faster to execute and faster to write due to the lower noise level of the syntax. It's far more expressive and definitely the preferred way of writing TornadoFX Applications.

That said, you won't notice a speed issue with either approach.